# Error in joining 3 tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to count the number of distinct customers after joining 3 tables. This is the query below.

I get the error `"mismatched input 'd' expecting ) near ')' in from source"`

```
select count(distinct(a.customer)) 
from (
    (select *
     from tab1
     where tab in (1)) c 
join (
    (select *
     from tab1
     where tab in (2)) a
     join
        (select *
         from tab1
         where tab in (3)) b
     on a.customer = b.customer) d
on c.customer = d.customer)
```

Comment: I attempted to format your query.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra parenthesis in your query which is misleading. Change to below

```
select count(distinct a.customer) 
from (
    select *
     from tab1
     where tab in (1)) c 
join (
    select *
     from tab1
     where tab in (2)) a on a.customer = c.customer
     join
        (select *
         from tab1
         where tab in (3)) b on c.customer = b.customer;
```